# Shorter-hand ternary logic

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

Is there a *shorter* way to use `ternary` logic in js when the `else` is **"null"**?

```
true ? console.log(true) :0; // current
```

I'm looking for something *like*

```
true ? console.log(true);
//or
true ?: console.log(true);
```

Just *curious*. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how this can be possible - in order to be ternary, there must be three things.  If you take one away, it is binary.

Comment: @PaulButcher I dare say that's the summation of Rocket's answer. It WAS ternary with the "third thing" always being null. Take that out and you get two things - hence the answer

Comment: Yes, but you can't use ternary anything without having three things to do it with.  What you have posted above is the absolute shortest way to use ternary logic.  Rocket's answer does not use ternary logic at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
true && console.log(true);
```

This works because the `&&` makes this expression into a boolean.  JavaScript will try to evaluate it.  If the first value is false, nothing happens because of short-circuiting.  If it's true, then it evaluates the second (the `console.log`).

You can also use the `||` as a quick way to do `empty` in JavaScript (beware of falsey values like `0` and `''`).

```
var a = false;
var b = a || 6; // b will be 6
```

Comment: Thinking about it now, this is just like `if(true) console.log(true);` but even shorter. Nice work.